# How to trigger enemy's area entered function while disabling player's hurtbox collision

Tags: 2d, godot, gdscript

I am making 2d platformer zombie game. When player entered enemy's hitbox area, enemy will enter Grab Attack State from Chase State. Once player entered enemy's hitbox area and enemy entered Grab Attack State, I would like to disable player's hurtbox collision. So I can avoid another enemy to be in Grab Attack State while player and enemy are in Grab Attack State. I tried to achieve this by simply disabling Player's hurtbox collision by `$CollisionShape2D.set_defferted("disabled", true)`. However, this will make enemy return to Idle state instantly, as Grab Attack State and Chase State will only happen when Player's hurtbox entered. I would appreciate if you could teach me how to keep enemy's Grab Attack State sequence while disabling player's hurtbox collision.

Answer (score 1):

For a good melee enemy solution, you want:

- Idle (a.k.a stand by): you already know this one.
- Windup (a.k.a anticipation): when the attack is being telegraphed to the player.
- Strike: When the attack can connect.
- Recovery (a.k.a follow through): If the attack failed to connect.

There are multiple ways to handle this. For example, you could have a state machine that triggers each animation (perhaps with some blending), or you could have an `AnimationTree` do it. Or you could use the `animation_finished` signal… Or it could be just one animation, and have a method call track that tells the script in what part of it is (you might be interested in "frame data" and how fighting games use it). However you handle it…

When the player enters the trigger area of the enemy, you will go into windup, and the appropriate animation must begin to play. If the attack is cancelable, then the behavior you have makes sense: leaving the trigger area returns the enemy to idle.

*Addendum: You might have a cancelable windup following by another state where it isn't cancelable but it can't contact yet. That state would be "commitment".*

When the windup animation is finished, you go into strike, which is when you check hit and hurt boxes. So the attack might connect or or not. If it does not connect you continue into recovery.

For a regular attack, you would do whatever damage mechanic you have.

---

But being this a grab, you need and extra grab state. For when the enemy is actually grabbing the player, not just attempting to grab the player.

So the enemy will enter this grab state when the attack actually connected. And then it does whatever it has to do to the player (e.g. throw it, hit it, whatever), and then release it (perhaps the player has to do some inputs, I don't know).

*I'm going to suggest a "movement disabled" state for the player where it does not take input and some other code is responsible for moving it, it is useful for cut scenes, and you can reuse it here. If the enemy is setting this state on the player, the enemy is also responsible from clearing it.*

And in sync with that you need to prevent prevent other enemies to attack※, ar at least prevent their attacks from connecting. How? There are a few options:

- Since at this point you already checked hit and hurt boxes, you can actually disable the collision (as you were trying to do). And remember that then the enemy must enable it when it releases the player.
- Another options is to have a "grabbing" node group, then the enemy can add itself there only if it is empty, if it wasn't consider it didn't connect and go into recovery. When the enemy releases the player it must exit the group.
- Similarly, you could store in metadata of the player (or in some other conveniente location) who is grabbing it. The enemies would set themselves on said metadata only if it was not set previously. The enemy that set itself will also be responsible from clearing the metadata when it releases the player.

※: Using a node group where the enemies that are attacking must join, but only if it is below a certain size, will allow you to limit how many enemies attack at the same time. Which is one more variable that affects difficulty, if you need it.